# how to verify client certificates using boost::asio SSL?

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, boost-asio

Below is the code snippet for SSL context initialization and verify callback registered.
If I connect SSL client with proper certificates it verifies the certificate and works as expected.

But if I connect client without any certificate then it allows connection(actually it should not allow connection without certificates). If SSL client do not send certificate then it do not call verify callback.

```
    boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method SSL_version =
            static_cast<boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method>(param_values[ID_PROTOCOL_VERSION].int32_value);

    // load certificate files
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context> context_ = boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context>(
            new boost::asio::ssl::context(SSL_version)); // parasoft-suppress BD-RES-LEAKS "The memory is allocated via boost::shared_ptr, hence it'll be deallocated automatically"

    p_ctx = boost::static_pointer_cast<void>(context_);

    context_->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds);

    context_->use_certificate_chain_file(cert_chain_file);
    context_->use_certificate_file(cert_file, boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    context_->use_private_key_file(cert_file, boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);

    context_->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
    context_->set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&verify_certificate_cb, _1, _2));
```

`verify_certificate_cb` callback function

```
bool verify_certificate_cb(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
{
    std::cout << "Function : " << __func__ << " ----------------- Line : " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    int8_t subject_name[256];
    X509_STORE_CTX *cts = ctx.native_handle();
    int32_t length = 0;
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    std::cout << "CTX ERROR : " << cts->error << std::endl;

    int32_t depth = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth(cts);
    std::cout << "CTX DEPTH : " << depth << std::endl;

    switch (cts->error)
    {
    case X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT:
        Debug(PRIORITY_ERROR, "X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT");
        break;
    case X509_V_ERR_CERT_NOT_YET_VALID:
    case X509_V_ERR_ERROR_IN_CERT_NOT_BEFORE_FIELD:
        Debug(PRIORITY_ERROR, "Certificate not yet valid!!");
        break;
    case X509_V_ERR_CERT_HAS_EXPIRED:
    case X509_V_ERR_ERROR_IN_CERT_NOT_AFTER_FIELD:
        Debug(PRIORITY_ERROR, "Certificate expired..");
        break;
    case X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN:
        Debug(PRIORITY_WARN, "Self signed certificate in chain!!!\n");
        preverified = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    const int32_t name_length = 256;
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), reinterpret_cast<char*>(subject_name), name_length);
    Debug(PRIORITY_INFO, "Verifying %s", subject_name);
    Debug(PRIORITY_INFO, "Verification status : %d", preverified);

    std::cout << "Function : " << __func__ << " ----------------- Line : " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    return preverified;
}
```

How can I modify the code that do not allow connection without proper certificate files?
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: how to do the verify_certificate_cb synchronously, without using set_verify_callback ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finally got the solution. One of my teammate has suggested to use flag `boost::asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert` in association with `boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer` and it worked.

updated line of code :

```
context_->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer | boost::asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);
```

Comment: Can you explain what is doing the extra flag?